# Best way to automatically set tick precision in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, luatex, python

I know  that I can manually set precisions like so:

```latex
x tick label style = {/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill, /pgf/number format/precision = 2},
y tick label style = {/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill, /pgf/number format/precision = 4},
scaled y ticks=false,
```

But is there a way to calculate and set the precision consistently? I'm using Python to generate the LaTeX code, so I'd rather not have to manually set precisions for every single plot, which are generated in a loop over multiple datasets, where different precisions are needed for different datasets

Edit 1: Here's an example page with plots whose Y-axis precision varies depending on the given data:
[image: Example of variable precisions on Y-axis]

Edit 2: I've posted an answer that seems to do the job, but I haven't tested it extensively

Comment: Hi, welcome! If the code is generated in Python you could do the calculation there I suppose. My first thought was calculate the range of the data you're plotting, and set the precision depending on the number of zeroes after the decimal (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/55048831), assuming ranges below 1.

Comment: What do you mean with "consistently" here? Can you give examples?

Comment: I edited the question to give an example

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I didn't read your comment before trying to solve it by myself. I'll try to implement the answer you linked, as it seems to be more _generalized_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to calculate the precisions according to the given data with Python:

```python
precision, max_precision = 0, 6
for p in range(max_precision):
    if np.max(data) < (3/2)*10**-p:
        precision += 1

y_tick_label_style = f"y tick label style = {{/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill, /pgf/number format/precision = {precision}}},"
```

I believe the *mantissa* (3/2 here) depends on the `pgfplots` settings, which are as follows for the example plots:

```latex
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.18, try min ticks = 2, max space between ticks = 50pt}
```